# Баланс скобок: обработать одинаковые открывающиеся и закрывающиеся скобки

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Код для нормальных скобок типа `{` и `}` или `[` и `]` или `{` и `]` .... всё хорошо работает а для вариантов когда открывающаяся и закрывающаяся однинаковые  типа `|` и `|` то....соответсвенно он вместо того что бы вынять из стека вносит туда.....

```
    var bracketsConfigMap = new Map();
    bracketsConfig.forEach(element => {
        bracketsConfigMap.set(element[0], element[1])
    });  
    let stack = [];
    let inStr = str.split('');
    let current;
    for (let index = 0; index < inStr.length; index++) {
        current = inStr[index];
        console.log('current = '+current)
        if (bracketsConfigMap.has(current)) {
            stack.push(current);
        }
        else {
            const last = stack.pop();
            if (current != bracketsConfigMap.get(last)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    if (stack.length === 0) return true; else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для случая с единственным видом сомнительных скобок линейное решение есть: надо помимо скобок в стеке держать количество палок между ними. В момент закрытия скобки надо проверить, что число палок чётное.

```js
function isValid(str) {
  var stack = [0]
  var pair = { '(':')', '[':']', '{':'}' }
  var end = { ')':1, ']':1, '}':1 }

  for (var ch of str) {
    if (ch === '|') {
      ++stack[stack.length - 1]
    } else if (pair[ch]) {
      stack.push(pair[ch])
      stack.push(0)
    } else if (end[ch]) {
      if (stack.pop() % 2 || stack.pop() !== ch) {
        return false
      }
    }
  }

  return stack.length === 1 && !(stack[0] % 2)
}

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', e => {
  e.target.style.color = isValid(e.target.value) ? 'green' : 'red'
})
```

```css
input { width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid; outline: none; }
```

```html
<input autofocus>
```

---

Ответ устарел. Я считал, что надо обработать многосимвольные скобки `(|`...`|)` и `(*`...`*)`.

> ```
> let inStr = str.split('');
> ```

```
let inStr = str && str.match(/\(\||\||)|\(\*|\*\)|./g);
```

Думаю, должно заработать.

Comment: Рекурсия помогает!!! спасибо за наводку!

Comment: Единственная допустимая семантика "одинаковых" скобок - это то, что такая скобка является закрывающей всегда, когда она *может* быть закрывающей. Это автоматически означает, что никакого смысла держать или проверять  "число палок" нет. Всякая палка сразу же аннигилируется с палкой на вершине стека (если на вершине тоже палка). Если на вершине - не палка, тогда и только тогда новая палка считается открывающей и кладется в стек. Это все, что нужно исправить.

Comment: @AnT, да, похоже на правду. Может ответ напишешь?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99227/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy-----).